# Limit of Taylor coefficients

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, sequence, mathematica-online

I want to calculate the following limit:

```
b[n_] := (D[1/(1 - t), {t, n}] /. {t -> 0})/Factorial[n]
Limit[b[n], n -> ∞]
(* Indeterminate *)
```

where `b[n]` represents the $n^\rm{th}$ Taylor coefficient of function $1/(1-t)$ at $t=0$.

1. Each $b_n$ is 1. Why does the limit return `Indeterminate` and not 1?
2. Is there any simple method to calculate the limit of Taylor coefficients of a rational function? Below is an example of a rational function:

```
(1 + t)/(-t (1 + t + t^3) + (1 + t) (1 - t^2)^3 (1 - t^4)^3 (1 - t^6)^3)
```

**Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks is advance.**

Comment: `b[n_] = Assuming[n >= 0, SeriesCoefficient[f[t], {t, 0, n}]]`

Answer (score 4):

Use [`DiscreteLimit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteLimit.html).

```
f = 1/(1 - t);
b = (D[1/(1 - t), {t, n}] /. {t -> 0})/Factorial[n]
(* ((-1)^n FactorialPower[-1, n])/n! *)

DiscreteLimit[b, n -> ∞]
(* 1 *)
```

Also, you don't need to calculate the coefficient via `D` and `Factorial` because there exists [`SeriesCoefficient`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesCoefficient.html).

```
b = SeriesCoefficient[f, {t, 0, n}]
(* Piecewise[{{1, n >= 0}}, 0] *)

DiscreteLimit[b, n -> ∞]
(* 1 *)
```

Now to your complicated rational function, for which it seems that the coefficients keep growing indefinitely.

```
f = (1 + t)/(-t (1 + t + t^3) + (1 + 
       t) (1 - t^2)^3 (1 - t^4)^3 (1 - t^6)^3);

Table[SeriesCoefficient[f, {t, 0, n}], {n, 0, 25}]
(* {1, 1, 4, 7, 20, 41, 100, 221, 515, 1164, 2679, 6096, 13980, 31889, 
    73002, 166725, 381369, 871473, 1992675, 4554587, 10412772, 23802307,
    54414141, 124388286, 284356379, 650034525} *)
```

You can obtain a general formula, which is an extremely long expression with 37 terms and many `Root` objects.

```
b = SeriesCoefficient[f, {t, 0, n}]
```

[image: SeriesCoefficient]

You may try using `Limit` or `DiscreteLimit` on this result if you are patient. However, with a bit dangerous approach by looking at the numerical representation, you may see that there are only exponential terms, and the largest base (by absolute value) is positive.

```
Collect[N[b], n] /. a_Complex :> Abs[a]
(* 0.225774 * (-1.4473)^n + ... + 0.685494 * 2.28601^n *)

Limit[N[b], n -> ∞]
∞
```

Comment: @ShrikantShekhar, please edit your question and include a concrete example of your rational function.

Comment: @ Domen Sur.
Here is the rational function 

$\frac{(1+t)}{(-t(1+t+t^3)+(1+t)(1-t^2)^3(1-t^4)^3(1-t^6)^3)}$

 for which I want to check ```DiscreteMaxLimit[a[n], n-> \[Infinity]]``` where ``` a[n] = ``` $n^th$ Taylor coefficient.

Comment: @ShrikantShekhar, please see my update.

Comment: Thanks it's helpful. But I have a question : 

What is numerical representation ??

 I will let you know if there is any question.

Comment: @ShrikantShekhar, as you see in the image, the expression contains so called [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects which are the _exact_ representation of a certain number. What I meant by "numerical representation" was the conversion of this objects to _"inexact"_ numbers (that have some _finite_ precision) by using [`N`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html).

Comment: @ Domen Thanks a lot for your kind help.